# WriteableBitmap doesn't render on Linux but works on UWP and Wasm

Tags: c#, xaml, cross-platform, uno-platform

Im trying to to render on the UI a red box using the WriteableBitmap object . The application works as intended on UWP :

[image: UWP]

And on Linux using Gtk.Skia, nothing is being displayed (Shares the same code) :

[image: Linux.Gtk.Skia]

Here is the C# code :

```
 public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        Paint();
    }
    private void Paint()
    {
        WriteableBitmap _wb = new WriteableBitmap(100, 100);

        byte[] imageArray = new byte[_wb.PixelHeight * _wb.PixelWidth * 4];

        for (int i = 0; i < imageArray.Length; i += 4)
        {
            imageArray[i] = 0;
            imageArray[i + 1] = 0;
            imageArray[i + 2] = 255;
            imageArray[i + 3] = 255;
        }

        using (Stream stream = _wb.PixelBuffer.AsStream())
        {
            stream.Write(imageArray, 0, imageArray.Length);

        }
        test.Source = _wb;

    }
}
```

XAML code :

```
<Page
x:Class="test.Uno.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d">

<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Image x:Name="test" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

Support for WriteableBitmap is not yet available on Skia. Here's the [related issue](https://github.com/unoplatform/uno/issues/4059) for this.

**Update (2020-09-18): WriteableBitmap is available for Skia GTK/WPF in Uno.UI 3.1.0-dev.364 and later.**